# Decoding Bitmap to ImageView without caching, preventing memory leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks, bitmap

So I've read all tutorials about `Bitmap` on http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html and it seems they manage them caching with classes at a very specific level. I also know there are libraries like **Universal Image Loader** that takes care of that for you.

But let's go simple, what if I just want to decode a single `Bitmap` from a file and place it on an `ImageView`. As far as I know, to prevent memory leaks you're not supposed to keep a reference to a `Bitmap` so how can this be achieved. Suppose the bitmap's file path is stored in the following string: `imagePath`.

Answer (score 1):

Its ok to hold a reference to the Bitmap object provided that you clean up once the Bitmap is no longer needed (e.g. when the activity is destroyed).

To ensure that you do not have any Bitmap-related leaks leaks:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
bitmap.recycle();    // frees the Bitmap instance
bitmap = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()); //File file
iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap); // ImageView iv
```